# Turbogears Toscawidget not working

Tags: forms, python-2.7, turbogears2

I searched in this [guide](https://www.wisdomjobs.com/e-university/turbogears-tutorial-1291/turbogears-crud-operations-17001.html) and this [guide](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/turbogears/turbogears_toscawidgets_forms.htm), and I followed the examples.
This is my controller in controllers/root.py:

```
@expose('rubrica.templates.submitForm')
def add(self, *args, **kw):  
    return dict(page='submitForm', form=SubmitForm)

@expose()
def save_record(self, **kw):
    print('save_record')
    new_contact = Contact(name = kw['name'], phone = kw['phone'])
    model.DBSession.add(new_contact)
    flash(message = "Added new contact")
    redirect('/index')
```

this is SubmitForm.py:

```
import tw2.core as twc
import tw2.forms as twf
class SubmitForm(twf.Form):
    class child(twf.TableLayout):
        name = twf.TextField(size = 20)
        phone = twf.TextField(size = 20)
        action = '/save_record'
        submit = twf.SubmitButton(value = 'Submit')
```

and this is the template:

```
<head py:block="head" py:strip="True">
    <title py:block="master_title">Aggiungi Contatto</title>
</head>
<body py:block="body" py:strip="True">
    <div>
        ${form.display(value = dict(title = 'Inserisci i dati'))}
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

The problem is that save_record is not called(`action = '/save_record'` should call it, but nothing happens)
I can't figure out why.. guess I did something wrong, or something is missing but I can't get it :)

Thanks for help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`action` and `submit` are properties of the `Form`, but you are specifying them in the `Layout`. Move the `action` and `submit` properties out in the parent scope and it should work as you expect:

```
import tw2.core as twc
import tw2.forms as twf

class SubmitForm(twf.Form):
    class child(twf.TableLayout):
        name = twf.TextField(size = 20)
        phone = twf.TextField(size = 20)

    action = '/save_record'
    submit = twf.SubmitButton(value = 'Submit')
```